# Async TcpClient events on data available c#

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, monitoring, tcpclient

I faced with problem of monitoring incoming data of TcpClient.
I need to make, mb, some event, which will be rised, when TcpClient.Available > 0. I need this, coz I want to use same socket(TcpClient) more than 1 time in both directions.
But I dont want to make infinite loop to do this.
Maybe there is some more better way to achieve that?
And, my whole network is working asynchronously, so I dont need to call stream.Read() to block some thread.

Comment: Just call `BeginRead()` instead of relying on `Available > 0`? Your callback will be called when data has been read.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to use same socket more than 1 time in both directions", but just in case - be aware that the TCP abstraction is just a *stream* of bytes (in each direction). It's not *messaging* (calls to send at one end are not guaranteed to be matched 1-1 with calls to receive at the other end). If you want messaging, it's up to you to implement it (or to move to a higher-level abstraction where it's implemented for you)

Comment: It will be good to read @CodeCaster [blog](http://codecaster.nl/blog/2012/08/sockets-and-protocols-exchanging-messages-using-bytes/) about this.  ;-)